# NullPointerException from DefaulListModel

Tags: java, swing, defaultlistmodel

I am working on a Swing GUI for a grading system. For some reason, my delete `Jbutton`, as well as the method that clears the model, started returning NPE's when called. They were working previously, and using the debugger I found the index was correct, I can't find a reason they aren't working.

Now, I can add to the model, but I can't clear or remove any elements for some reason.

EDIT: I just did a test and it does work without, this code doesn't appear to be an issue.

```
DefaultListModel<Student> model; //List model in View class

private void handleDeleteButton(){ //Controller class method to handle delete button
   int indexToDelete = sv.listSelectedIndex(); 
   if(indexToDelete >= 0){
       model.remove(indexToDelete); //remove Student object from DefaultListModel 
   }
```

}

```
public int listSelectedIndex(){ //method in the View class to return the selected list index
    return studentList.getMinSelectionIndex();
}

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gradingsystem.SView.setFields(SView.java:136)
at gradingsystem.SController.valueChanged(SController.java:181)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(JList.java:1798)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(JList.java:1812)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeIndexInterval(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:677)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.intervalRemoved(BasicListUI.java:2601)
at javax.swing.AbstractListModel.fireIntervalRemoved(AbstractListModel.java:179)
at javax.swing.DefaultListModel.remove(DefaultListModel.java:498)
at gradingsystem.SController.handleDeleteButton(SController.java:63)
at gradingsystem.SController.actionPerformed(SController.java:96)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:104)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:672)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:670)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:684)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:683)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace to get more info

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a simple careless java error. You've declared your DefaultListModel variable but in your code posted have never initialized it.

In short, you have:

```
DefaultListModel<Student> model;  // model is null
```

but need:

```
DefaultListModel<Student> model = new DefaultListModel<Student>(); // model not null
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, then your error lies elsewhere in code not shown, and you'll want to create and post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @user3133608: yep, you'll need to show enough code to reproduce your problem, as well as a stacktrace of the exception, but not too much code to over-whelm us with a lot of unrelated code. Please check the link I've provided above.

Comment: Thanks for the info, its my first post here. Simple test proved as I sorta thought that there is something going wrong elsewhere in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the DefaultListModel model is some kind of immutable, so you can not perform delete operation. Check that ;)

Comment: And how would this cause a NPE? Answer: it can't.